# Call stored procedure by passing List<T> as input parameters

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, dapper

I've met some problem that I can not insert a list of objects into table by call stored procedure.

Can any one give me some hint?

Thanks very much :D

Table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTest]
(
    [ColA] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [ColB] [int] NULL,
    [ColC] [datetime] NULL
)
```

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.myspMyTest
    @ColA varchar(10), 
    @ColB int,
    @ColC datetime
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Test.dbo.MyTest (ColA, ColB, ColC) 
    VALUES (@ColA, @ColB, @ColC)       
END
```

Class definition:

```
public class TEST2
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }
    public DateTime C { get; set; }
}
```

My code snippet:

```
var conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
conn.Open();

var procedure = "myspMyTest";                     

var list = new List<TEST2>();
list.Add(new TEST2 { A = "daskjf", B = 453, C = DateTime.Now });
list.Add(new TEST2 { A = "hjdgkfl", B = 456456, C = DateTime.Now });

var parameters = new DynamicParameters();

// Don't know how to go on from here...
```

Comment: You can either call the procedure multiple times in `.CommandText` or define a table type and table value parameter (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters).

Answer (score 0):

Using dapper you can insert multiple records in a table without a stored procedure - like this:

```
int records = connection.Execute("insert MyTest (ColA,ColB,ColC) values(@ColA, @ColB, @ColC)", new List<TEST2>
{
    new TEST2{A = "daskjf", B = 453, C = DateTime.Now},
    new TEST2{A = "hjdgkfl", B = 456456, C = DateTime.Now},
});
```

If the stored procedure is a must then you have to use a table-valued function as a parameter in the stored procedure.